# How can my chrome extension listen for a data loading event on a webpage with Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a chrome extension which needs to modify data that is loaded after the user clicks on a button on the given webpage. I have tried simply using the HTML DOM onClick event, which doesn't quite work because after the button is clicked, the data is not yet loaded so there is no data to be modified (I just want to add a column to the table that is loaded in after the button click). I have tried using the deprecated SubTreeModified route, but this does not seem like a good practice, among a myriad of other issues.

***tl;dr:***  Website has a button -> click opens a panel which loads data into a table for display. I want to modify that table, but I can't use onClick because there is a delay between the click and the loaded data.

Comment: Can you share your extension code?

Comment: Use MutationObserver. Or spoof XMLHttpRequest [in the context of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/insert-code-into-the-page-context-using-a-content-script).